# I am new to flutter and I think I have misunderstood the widget and layout system

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

If I want to add more buttons and text widgets where and how should I do it, should I make some sort of column and row system or am I totally off? And is my code programmed wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const HomeScreen(),
  );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text('Dice'),
              centerTitle: true,
            ),
            body: const Dice()));
  }
}

class Dice extends StatefulWidget {
  const Dice({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Dice> createState() => _DiceState();
}

class _DiceState extends State<Dice> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Image.asset('images/1.png'))),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Image.asset('images/2.png'))),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Image.asset('images/3.png'))),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Image.asset('images/4.png'))),
          Expanded(
              child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                  child: Image.asset('images/5.png')))
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

}

I am going to add variables to the children in the container later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better understanding I would recommend you checking out this medium article. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-layout-cheat-sheet-5363348d037e Here you can view all the important layout widgets you can use.

In general you have a widget tree starting by MaterialApp and you can add as many items as you want. In flutter if you want multiple widgets you can use `Row` and `Column` for that. Both of them provides a children property in brackets [] there you can add multiple widgets inside separated by comma.

Most of the other widgets are also able to provide a children property where you can add even more children widgets. That's how the widget tree in general works. Actually you have unlimited possibility’s.

Your code is totally fine. By the way you can also create custom widgets if the plenty widgets of flutter doesn't fit your use case.

In your example you can add whatever you want in your row, text, more images, buttons, everything you like.

Here you can check out the official widget catalog of flutter: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets

Comment: Yea I can understand that. If it helped you please accept it as answer so other people can also profit

Comment: Thanks. So classes with widgets in them can also be put in rows and colums? Oops accendentally deleted first comment.

Comment: Exactly. You could add another Row for example I n your row children line which has other widgets. Also you could add a button widget for example which has a child with text for the button. If you’re familiar with html or react components you can compare it a little bit with this

Comment: Some widgets are just there to do something in your widget tree, you would follow the nesting concept which is meant to be used in flutter. For example if you want to make your text button added in the row centered you would add a Center() widget where you put the text button as child of the center. Let’s say you want to make an element clickable you would wrap your element with GestureDetector widget where your element is the child from the widget. As you can see nesting is the concept of building this so called widget tree

Comment: Now when i add Dice() into a colum in body i get a Bottom overflowed by infinity pixels. Is it related to me not giving the children in dice and height?

Comment: It’s because of column. Colum and rows need informations about the available space or fox sizes. You can wrap the column with expanded for example. But for this use cases there are plenty ways you can go further

Comment: I removed body in dice and it seems to fix it. dont understand why though

Comment: Don’t know your exact code but body belongs to scaffold. This is the only place with a body. Anyways if my answer helped you It would be glad to accept my answer with the check icon

Comment: I had accendentally put a scaffold in a scaffold. Pressed the check mark would upvote if i could :´(

Answer (score 0):

You can place a Column/ListView in between your Center and Row widgets, then you could add multiple rows to it like below:

```
class _DiceState extends State<Dice> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
                child: Column(
                    children: [
                        Row(
                            children: [
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        child: Image.asset('images/1.png'))),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        child: Image.asset('images/2.png'))),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        child: Image.asset('images/3.png'))),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        child: Image.asset('images/4.png'))),
                                Expanded(
                                    child: Container(
                                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                        child: Image.asset('images/5.png')))
                                ],
                            ),
                        Row(children: [/* more content here */]),
                    ],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```